# Spacemacs: shortcut to jump from opened orgmode file to Neotree pane

Tags: spacemacs, neotree

I am using Spacemacs. So I have a Neotree pan that I open with `Spc-f-t` and that works fine. Then I can navigate down the tree to open a file with `l` and that will move the cursor from the Neotree pane to the opened file, which is in the adjacent pane. Then I can make edits in the org-mode file.

**Now, I want to know if there is a key shortcut to jump from the org-mode file back to the Neotree pane?** So that way I can move to the a subsequent file in the directory.

I checked the Spacemacs and the NeoTree documentation, but did not find any reference to going from an opened buffer back to the NeoTree pane. And that kind of makes sense, since the shortcuts of the opened pane (org-mode or otherwise) would dictate behavior. But I was wondering if there was a way to go back and forth between opened files and the Neotree pane.

I can use the `Spc-f-t` key twice to close the pane and reopen it. That will work. But I was wondering if there was a smoother way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find [Neotree layer documentation](http://develop.spacemacs.org/layers/+filetree/neotree/README.html) in the develop branch documentation site for Spacemacs. The shortcut to jump to the neotree window is `SPC 0`.

> To select the NeoTree window, press SPC 0. The NeoTree window always has the number 0 so it does not shift the current number of the other windows.

I assume this will work on the master branch as well, but have not tested it myself.